# MySql/PHP Simple Report Query

Tags: php, mysql

I'm running a MySQL/PHP and i'm trying to display a simple report that tracks when a salesrep contacts a customer.  I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong, as i'm a novice in this area.  The simplest solution to me seems extremely convoluted (making a separate recordset for each figure).  I figured there would have to be a simpler way.

I'm looking to display the number of contacts made during the current week/month/year in a simple table.  see below.  any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
      |Current|Current|       |
      | Week  | Month | YTD   |
------|-------|-------|-------|
Brian |  7    |   14  |  37   |
------|-------|-------|-------|
Chad  |  0    |   15  |  27   |
------|-------|-------|-------|
David |  11   |   26  |  52   |
------|-------|-------|-------|
```

Current recordsets

```
mysql_select_db($database_Sales, $Sales);
$query_rsCurWeek = "SELECT Sales.rep, COUNT(*) FROM Sales WHERE YEARWEEK(`date`, 1) = YEARWEEK(CURDATE(), 1) GROUP BY Sales.rep";
$rsCurWeek = mysql_query($query_rsCurWeek, $Sales) or die(mysql_error());
$row_rsCurWeek = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsCurWeek);
$totalRows_rsCurWeek = mysql_num_rows($rsCurWeek);

mysql_select_db($database_Sales, $Sales);
$query_rsCurMonth = "SELECT Sales.rep, COUNT(*) FROM Sales WHERE MONTH(date) = MONTH(CURDATE()) GROUP BY Sales.rep";
$rsCurMonth = mysql_query($query_rsCurMonth, $Sales) or die(mysql_error());
$row_rsCurMonth = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsCurMonth);
$totalRows_rsCurMonth = mysql_num_rows($rsCurMonth);

mysql_select_db($database_Sales, $Sales);
$query_rsCurYear = "SELECT Sales.rep, COUNT(*) FROM Sales WHERE YEAR(date) =         
YEAR(CURDATE()) GROUP BY Sales.rep";
$rsCurYear = mysql_query($query_rsCurYear, $Sales) or die(mysql_error());
$row_rsCurYear = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsCurYear);
$totalRows_rsCurYear = mysql_num_rows($rsCurYear);
```

Current Output Table

```
<table width="400" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
<th width="175" align="center"></th>
<th width="75" align="center">Current<br />Week</th>
<th width="75" align="center">Current<br />Month</th>
<th width="75" align="center">YTD</th>
</tr>
<?php do { ?>
<tr>
<th align="left"><?php echo $row_rsCurYear['rep']; ?></th>
<td align="center"><?php echo $row_rsCurWeek['COUNT(*)']; ?></td>
<td align="center"><?php echo $row_rsCurMonth['COUNT(*)']; ?></td>
<td align="center"><?php echo $row_rsCurYear['COUNT(*)']; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php } while ($row_rsCurWeek = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsCurWeek)); ?>
```

Comment: Can you provide your code so that people can help you with your issue? Currently there isn't enough details for anyone to debug what is wrong with what you've already done.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Can you please read [ask] and consider editing your question to include some code and a specific issue with the code

Comment: Sorry.  Yes, I updated my issue with the code I'm currently using.

Answer (score 0):

```
try{

  $sql = "SELECT * FROM contacts";   

  $result = $pdo->query($sql);

  if($result->rowCount() > 0){

    echo "<table>";

        echo "<tr>";

            echo "<th>username</th>";

            echo "<th>current_week</th>";

            echo "<th>current_month</th>";

            echo "<th>ytd</th>";

        echo "</tr>";

    while($row = $result->fetch()){

        echo "<tr>";

            echo "<td>" . $row['username'] . "</td>";

            echo "<td>" . $row['current_week'] . "</td>";

            echo "<td>" . $row['current_month'] . "</td>";

            echo "<td>" . $row['ytd'] . "</td>";

        echo "</tr>";

    }
    echo "</table>";
    // Free result set
    unset($result);
  } else{
    echo "No records matching your query were found.";
  }
} catch(PDOException $e){
 die("ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . $e->getMessage());
}
```